# Vba multy loop in columns

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I'm not a vba developer but they asked me to make a macro in VBA and I don't know how to do it. I have a excel sheet in which there are several columns.

```
Date    Activity   ActivityType  Hours
```

In order: Column A,B,C,D. 
Ok. Column B has a list of several options:

```
Activity1
Activity2
Activity3
```

and the same thing is for the C column

```
Type1
Type2
Type3
```

Ok, now, I have to make a loop in the B column for each Activity. Starting for Activity1 I have to loop the C column for each activity. So,

```
first loop will be Activity1 - Type1, Activity1 - Type2, Activity3 - Type3.

Second loop: Activity2 - Type1 etc etc.
```

In the first loop for example I need copy the rows of Activity1 - Type1 in another sheet and for the other I have to do the same thing. For each activity and ActivityType. I don't know if is clear as question but I don't know how do these operations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attempting to create a Cartesian Product, which would be all cells in column B "multiplied" by all cells in Column C. Here is a simple VBA sub which outputs the results on "Sheet2" of your workbook. Quick disclaimer, this is done without my VBA editor, so it might have a minor syntax error.

```
Sub MyFunction()

    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim lRow1 As Long
    Dim lRow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim output as String

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").CurrentRegion
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    lRow1 = rng1.Rows.Count
    lRow2 = rng2.Rows.Count
    k = 0

    For i = 1 To lRow1
        For j = 1 To lRow2
            k = k + 1
            output = rng1.Cells(i,1).Value & " - " & rng2.Cells(j,1).Value
            ws3.Range("A" & k).Value = output
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub or function not defined` :(

Comment: I just tested and this works perfect in Office 2007, hmm. Are you using the VBA editor (ALT+F11)? Did you place this code in a `Module`? Did you execute it by pressing F5 in the VBA editor?